# Prestashop : modify the order of appearance of payment modules in backoffice order

Tags: php, overriding, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to customize (with override) the AdminOrdersController.php in prestashop to simplify the life of my sales guys.
When they create an order in the Backoffice, I want to have a specific payment method selected in the lis by default.
For the moment, I just modified the file _select_payment.tpl by adding a array_reverse because my favourite payment method is the latest in the list, but I'm not satisfied with that.

```
    <select name="payment_module_name" id="payment_module_name">
  {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
    {foreach from=array_reverse($payment_modules) item='module'}
      <option value="{$module->name}" {if isset($smarty.post.payment_module_name) && $module->name == $smarty.post.payment_module_name}selected="selected"{/if}>{$module->displayName}</option>
    {/foreach}
  {else}
      <option value="{l s='Back office order'}">{l s='Back office order'}</option>
  {/if}
</select>
```

How can I implement the "selected" option in the list on the chosen element ?
(I want to do it also in another list, the order state one)

Thanks for your ideas !

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Edit your question and add this details :), in comment it's not easy to read and understand :)